# Janela no visual studio ao debugar método

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, debug

Tenho lidado com alguns métodos bem robustos que alteram ou inserem dados em diversas tabelas. É demorado debugar e mapear todas as tabelas que são afetadas pela rotina.

Existe alguma janela tipo **Immediate Window** ou **Quick Watch** no Visual Studio que mostre todas as entidades que estão sendo afetadas durante o debugging?

Se alguém souber algo que possa me ajudar ficarei muito grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu utilizo o AUTOS do visual studio para verificar todos os objetos modificados durante o debug.

Links para te auxiliar:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bhawk8xd.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290702(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

- **Autos** mostra variáveis utilizadas na linha atual de execução (o lugar onde o depurador está parado) (CTRL+ALT+V, A, ou Debug > Windows > Autos);
- **Locals** mostra variáveis dentro do escopo atual, o que geralmente é a função ou método que está sendo executado (CTRL+ALT+V, L, ou Debug > Windows > Locals);
- **Watch** permite escolher quais variáveis deseja monitorar independentemente do contexto (valores só apareceção quando disponíveis) (CTRL+ALT+W, 1, ou Debug > Windows > Watch 1).

Uma particularidade que considero bastante interessante é que as variáveis com valores alterados, ficarão em vermelho, facilitando o rastreio de alterações na depuração.

*Os atalhos para estas janelas são disponíveis apenas em modo de debug*

[Referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows)